# Shopware6 Social Shopping: Google Shopping Feed: Varianten template <g:size>

Tags: shopware, shopware6

H

I added structured data values such as:

<g:color>, <g:material>.

```
    {% for properties in product.properties %}
      {% if properties.group.name == "Kolor" %}
         <g:color>{{ properties.name }}</g:color>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
       {% for properties in product.properties %}
          {% if properties.group.name == "Skład" %}
             <g:material>{{ properties.name }}</g:material>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

, but I don't know how I can add <g:size> from product variants?

First of all you have to enable "Export variants as discrete products" in the settings of your product comparison sales channel.

There are two separate association to properties:

- `product.properties` for general properties, not necessarily variant specific
- `product.options` which define the combination of properties for a specific variant.

You may want to iterate `product.options` instead.

0

I tried this:

```
{%- if product.variation -%}
{%- for variation in product.variation -%}
    {%- if variation.group == 'Kolor' -%}
       <g:color>{{ variation.option }}</g:color>
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if variation.group == 'Wymiary' -%}
       <g:size>{{ variation.option }}</g:size>
     {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to enable "Export variants as discrete products" in the settings of your product comparison sales channel.

There are two separate association to properties:

- `product.properties` for general properties, not necessarily variant specific
- `product.options` which define the combination of properties for a specific variant.

You may want to iterate `product.options` instead.

Comment: You can show me an example of how it should look properly.